# Angle labels in opposite direction?

Tags: canvasjs

Currently, it seems that CanvasJS only supports angling labels in one direction (with the baseline on the left), as shown in the image below.  I would like to rotate the text in the opposite direction (With the baseline for the text being on the right), as shown by the arrows.

[image: CanvasJS chart labels]

So far, I have tried setting the axisX labelAngle to 90, 270, -45, -90, and -270.  None of these have resulted in shifting the baseline to the right like I want, and have all forced the text to a max of 90 degrees with the baseline on the left.

Is this possible in the current version?  @Devs: If not available in current version, would it be possible to add in support for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set angle to negative value to make it rotated the other way-round, as shown in this screenshot.
[image]
Here is an example.

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
      axisX:{
        title: "labels at -45 deg",
        labelAngle: -45
      },
      data: [
      {
        type: "column",
        dataPoints: [

        { x: 10, y: 71, label: "cat 1" },
        { x: 20, y: 55, label: "cat 2" },
        { x: 30, y: 50, label: "cat 3" },
        { x: 40, y: 65, label: "cat 4" },
        { x: 50, y: 95, label: "cat 5" },
        { x: 60, y: 68, label: "cat 6" },
        { x: 70, y: 28, label: "cat 7" },
        { x: 80, y: 34, label: "cat 8" },
        { x: 90, y: 14, label: "cat 9" }
        ]
      }
      ]
    });

    chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 360px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Comment: Thats interesting.  Yesterday, when I tried that on http://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/axisx/labelangle/, it kept the same angle.  Must have been my bad internet connection or something.  Thanks!